# App rejected by Itunes Connect - dynamic libraries

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted my App to the App Store, but it got rejected. I received an email saying :

> Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.

I'm not using CocoaPods, so all external frameworks are installed manually. I've already tried to change the Dynamic library install Name to :

```
$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)
```

but I still get the same error from Apple.

EDIT: Still no solution for me.

- I included my .tbd in the `other linker flags` as suggested [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4572#8609)
- I added `@executable_path/Frameworks`, `@executable_path/../Frameworks` and `@loader_path/Frameworks` to `Runpath Search Paths` as suggested on several posts.
- I tried everything from [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160820051224/http://www.toddseiler.com/mac-dylib-rpath-framework-bundle-explaination/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by deleting all my external frameworks and libraries, and reinstalling them with CocoaPods.